How do I prove that if $f ∈ C^2(\Bbb R^n)$ is a convex function, $z ∈ \Bbb R^n$ is a critical point of $f$ if and only if it is a global minimizer?
I have worked a proof. However I am quite unsure about the correctness and wanted to hear some opinions from you.

Proof of forward implication ($\implies$). If $z$ is a critical point and $f$ is convex, then:
$$
f(z) -f(x) \ge Df_x(z-x),
$$
Since $z$ is a critical point, this implies that the gradient of $f$ is $0$. We can equate $Df_x$ with the gradient and obtain:
$$
f(z)-f(x) \ge 0
$$
or
$$
f(z) \ge f(x)\
$$
thus $z$ is a global minimizer of $f$.

Proof of reverse implication ($\;\Longleftarrow\;$). If $z$ is a global minimizer, then for all $x$ in $\Bbb R^n$
$$
f(z) \le f(x). 
$$
This means that the gradient of $f$ is $0$ and $z$ is therefore a critical point.



Use Mathjax to write math formulae.
